# Powershell Expression Hashtables to CSV

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to ouput some data Im pulling from ActiveDirectory into a CSV but the output is not what I am expecting. How do I export these hashtables value into a CSV? I have no doubt there is a simple answer to this but my google fu seems to be failing me today.

```
    foreach ($user in $user_data)
        {
            @{ name = 'DisplayName'; expression = { $user.DisplayName } },
            @{ name = 'Email'; expression = { $user.EmailAddress } },
            @{ name = 'AccountName'; expression = { $user.SamAccountName } },
            @{ name = 'Description'; expression = { $user.Description } },
            @{ name = "PasswordLastSet"; expression = { [datetime]::FromFileTime($user.pwdLastSet) } },
            @{ name = 'Staff Number'; expression = { $user.pager } },
            @{ name = 'LastBadPasswordAttempt'; expression = { $user.LastBadPasswordAttempt } },
            @{ name = 'LastLogonDate'; expression = { $user.LastLogonDate } },
            @{ name = 'logonCount'; expression = { $user.logonCount } },
            @{ name = 'Enabled'; expression = { $user.Enabled } } |
            Export-Csv $path2 -Append -NoTypeInformation
        }
```

Comment: Why use hashtables when you can output custom objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using calculated properties syntax, you can simply just use `Select-Object` rather than looping:

```
$user_data | Select-Object @{ name = 'DisplayName'; expression = { $_.DisplayName } },
        @{ name = 'Email'; expression = { $_.EmailAddress } },
        @{ name = 'AccountName'; expression = { $_.SamAccountName } },
        @{ name = 'Description'; expression = { $_.Description } },
        @{ name = "PasswordLastSet"; expression = { [datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet) } },
        @{ name = 'Staff Number'; expression = { $_.pager } },
        @{ name = 'LastBadPasswordAttempt'; expression = { $_.LastBadPasswordAttempt } },
        @{ name = 'LastLogonDate'; expression = { $_.LastLogonDate } },
        @{ name = 'logonCount'; expression = { $_.logonCount } },
        @{ name = 'Enabled'; expression = { $_.Enabled } } |
            Export-Csv $path2 -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: And there we have it, simple. Thank you AdminOfThings

Comment: And I learnt I am using calculated properties syntax. This could be why my googlefu wasnt working so well. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For the output you want, I guess it would be better to use an array of custom objects.

```
$users = @()
ForEach($user in $user_data)
{

    $users += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        DisplayName = [String]$user.DisplayName;
        Email = [String]$user.EmailAddress;
        AccountName = [String]$user.SamAccountName;
        Description = [String]$user.Description;
        PasswordLastSet = [datetime]::FromFileTime($user.pwdLastSet);
        StaffNumber = [String]$user.pager;
        LastBadPasswordAttempt = [datetime]::FromFileTime($user.LastBadPasswordAttempt);
        LastLogonDate = [datetime]::FromFileTime($user.LastLogonDate);
        logonCount = [Int]$user.logonCount;
        Enabled = [Bool]$user.Enabled;
    }
}
$users | Export-Csv -Path $path2 -NoTypeInformation
```